# Incorporar resultado de regresión lineal en otro dataframe y de donde obtengo los nombres de las variables

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo el siguiente data frame en donde se encuentran los datos:

```
set.seed(666)
tabla_a <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,3000,replace = TRUE), ncol=30))
```

y otro data frame en donde quiero guardar el resultado de cada una de las regresiones con las variables especificadas con la siguiente sentencia:

```
lm.beta(lm(formula = dependiente ~ independiente, data = tabla_b))$standardized.coefficients[2]
dependiente = c("X1","X1","X1","X1","X1")
independiente = c("X2","X3","X12","X20", "X21")
tabla_b = data.frame(dependiente, independiente)
```

¿Alguien podría decirme como incorporar a tabla_b el resultado de la regresion como una columna adicional?
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Antes que nada, no dupliques preguntas, esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/382743/incorporar-resultado-de-regresi%c3%b3n-lineal-en-otro-dataframe-y-de-donde-obtengo-lo eliminala si consideras que esta nueva es la adecuada. Ahora bien, ¿Que entiendes por el resultado de la regresión? ¿los valores ajustados? ¿la predicción? ¿los coeficientes estandarizados?

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente, lo que buscas sería generar un modelo de regresión simple por cada variable del vector `independiente`, y el resultado dejarlo salvarlo como columna de `tabla_b`. Para esto necesitarás:

- Un ciclo que itere por cada variable independiente y realice la regresión, la formula puede construirse directamente desde cadenas y trasformarse en formula mediante `as.formula()`
- Una lista dónde salvar el coficiente que buscas, o en definitiva cualquier otro dato que necesites

Finalmente, con el ciclo completo, tendremos una lista de coeficientes que simplemente habrá que transformar en un vector y agregarlo como columna a `table_b`:

```
library(lm.beta)

set.seed(666)
tabla_a <-data.frame(matrix(sample(1:5,3000,replace = TRUE), ncol=30))

dependiente = "X1"
independiente = c("X2","X3","X12","X20", "X21")
coeficientes <- list()
for (var in independiente) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste(dependiente, "~ ", var))
  fit <- lm(data = tabla_a, formula = formula)
  coeficientes[[var]] <- lm.beta(fit)$standardized.coefficients[2]
}

tabla_b = data.frame(dependiente, independiente)
tabla_b$coeficiente <- unlist(coeficientes) 

tabla_b

  dependiente independiente coeficiente
1          X1            X2 -0.08760396
2          X1            X3  0.04449120
3          X1           X12  0.12002269
4          X1           X20 -0.21159223
5          X1           X21 -0.26675073
```

Comment: Entiendo pero no conozco de antemano el nombre de dichas variables ni cuantas son, por tanto necesito hacer referencia a la columna

Comment: No entiendo, para hacer una regresión necesitas conocer de antemano la variable dependiente y las independientes, como es que no las conoces de antemano?

Comment: Claro, por eso tengo esa segunda base que me indica los nombres de las variables de la regresion. Que puede ir cambiando los nombres y pueden ser mas o menos filas.

Comment: además de que la formulacion está corriendo una regresion lineal multiple y requiero una regresion lineal simple

Comment: Creo que estoy empezando a entender, quieres hacer una regresión por cada variable independiente e ir salvandola en un `data.frame`?

Comment: Si! en función de las variables señaladas en ese data frame. Gracias Patricio

Comment: @Luis, revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias patricio, solo corregiría:
independiente = tabla_b$independiente
@patricio moracho